# CCNET Build Publisher with mutlipe source dir

Tags: c#, asp.net, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CCNet and want to use build publisher to copy from more than one sourcedir, is there any workaround to do that, keep in mind that I want to make the build folder labelled with the build number . 
here is my code :

```
 <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>D:\CCNETTest1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1</sourceDir>
    <publishDir>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CI</publishDir>
    <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
  </buildpublisher>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could not specify more than one sourcedir in buildpublisher, so if you want to, you have to use before
create a folder that will contain all your sourcedir you want

create nant copy :

```
<copy todir="${target.dir}\firstsource">
    <fileset basedir="firstsource">
        <include name="*.*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
<copy todir="${target.dir}\secondsource">
    <fileset basedir="secondsource">
        <include name="*.*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

and after all your source are in target.dir folder use your buildpublisher but specify for sourceDir , folder that contains all folder you want...

```
 <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>$(target.dir)</sourceDir>
    <publishDir>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CI</publishDir>
    <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
  </buildpublisher>
```